# Number of instances or the content of the instances more important (machine learning)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, document-classification

Say in the document classification domain, if I'm having a dataset of 1000 instances but the instances (documents) are rather of small content; and I'm having another dataset of say 200 instances but each individual instance with richer content. If IDF is out of my concern, will the number of instances really matter in training? Do classification algorithms sort of take that into account?

Thanks.
sam

Comment: I don't understand the question. Take what into account? What exactly are you asking? What algorithm are you thinking about? (each behaves differently) and what are your features from the text?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear to you. By that I mean, do classification algorithms like SVM, kNN,  NaiveBayes take the number of instances in the training data set into account? In a text classification problem, the features will be words or N-grams.

Comment: OK, that I can understand - but I cannot understand what are you referring to about the size of each document in the question.. Also there is more then one way to take words or N-grams as features..

Comment: yes there are more than one way to do that I agree. If I have a dataset1 with many instances and a dataset2 with few instances and both datasets gives the same amount of information, does the number of instances matter in training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pose this as a general machine learning problem. The simplest problem that can help you understand how the size of training data matters is curve fitting.

The uncertainty and bias of a classifier or a fitted model are functions of the sample size. Small sample size is a well known problem which we often try to avoid by collecting more training samples. This is because the uncertainty estimation of non-linear classifiers is estimated by a linear approximation of the model. And this estimation is accurate only if a large number samples are available as the main condition of [the central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

The proportion of outliers is also an important factor you should consider when deciding on the training sample size. If a larger sample size means a greater proportion of outliers then should limit the sample size.

The document size is actually is an indirect indicator of feature space size. If for example from each document you have got only 10 features then you're trying to separate/classify the documents in a 10-dimensional space. If you have got 100 features in each document then the same is happening in a 100-dimensional space. I guess it's easy for you to see drawing lines that separate the documents in a higher dimension is easier.

For both document size and sample size the rule of thumb is go to as high as possible but in practice this is not possible. And for example, if you estimate the uncertainty function of the classifier then you find a threshold that sample sizes higher than that lead to virtually no reduction of uncertainty and bias. Empirically you can also find this threshold  for some problems by Monte Carlo simulation.

Most engineers don't bother to estimate uncertainty and that often leads to sub-optimal behavior of the methods they implement. This is fine for toy problems but in real-world problems considering uncertainty of estimations and computation is vital for most systems. I hope that answers your questions to some degree.